# Windows firewall problem - can't use GameRanger

Tags: udp, windows-firewall

I have a problem that whenever I try to host a room or join another room game I get windows firewall problem (that either router or firewall blocking me of entering/hosting a game). I followed [GR instructions](https://www.gameranger.com/support/network/?i_ip=3232235705&x_ip=772897240&r_ip=3232235521&rt=1&pp=1) and I set up my UDP connection like this:
[image]

Also I enabled GR though windows firewall:
[image]

Moreover, I turned off the windows firewall, windows defender. I restarted the router.. And nothing seems to work. :(

Comment: You can run below command to capture NetEvents and see if the packets are being dropped by Firewall and if so by which rule.

netsh.exe wfp cap start keywords=19
<Try to Host game>
netsh.exe wfp cap stop

This will generate a CAB file containing wfpdiag.xml. Search it using port or remoteIp to find the event.

Useful Link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13894.troubleshooting-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-in-windows-server-2012.aspx#Capturing_Firewall_and_IPsec_Events_with_Netsh_WFP